# Exc_bad_access on BOOL Getter in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, getter-setter

I want to make some operations when boolean values of property goes true to false and false to true.
I've set the getter setter for that, so I can do those operations on setter of boolean property.

But always crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2, can anyone help me to understand this what's wrong I'm doing here.

```
var reportActivityStarted:Bool {
        set {
            if self.reportActivityStarted {
                //Operations when boolean is true
            }else{
                //Operations when boolean is false
            }
        }
        get{
            return self.reportActivityStarted
        }
    }
```

When I changes it's boolean value, it crashes at **get{**

```
self.reportActivityStarted = true
```

Comment: Inside set, you should refer the value using the 'newValue'  and should not access self.reportActivityStarted.

Comment: @Martin R - can I know where you found this question in stackoverflow. as I searched for it, but didn't found relevant.

Comment: Type `[swift] EXC_BAD_ACCESS get set` into the search field, it is among the result list.

Comment: @Martin R - the link you have given it's recursive. I'm not changing the boolean value on setter. check the link you have provided and let me know how you think it's dublicate

Comment: Your setter calls the getter method, and the getter calls itself recursively. It is the same issue.

Comment: I clearly mention that I'm getting **[swift] EXC_BAD_ACCESS** on **get{**

Comment: @Martin R - Look at that question's answer, it's calling the setter from within the setter.

Comment: @Martin R - I'm not anyway setting the boolean in my setter. is it looks like that in my question.?

Comment: In your setter method you call `if self.reportActivityStarted`. That calls the getter method!! And the getter method calls itself recursively. It is really the same issue: `get` or `set` in a computed property must not call itself. The solution is to use property observers, as in the referenced Q&A.

Comment: And btw, just look at the stack backtrace when the exception occurs: You should *see* the recursion.

Comment: @Martin R - Okay. I thought my case is different, I understand now. I already checked that question's answer and it was mention that he called the setter from within the setter, so misunderstood the case and thought might be different. Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted by *@Unheilig* you are generating an **infinite recursive call**. Infact the getter of `reportActivityStarted` is recursively invoking itself.

If you want to run some logic when a property is set or retrieved then you should use a **property observer** like this:

```
var reportActivityStarted: Bool {
    willSet(newValue) {
        switch reportActivityStarted {
        case true: print("reportActivityStarted is true before assignment") // <- your logic goes here
        case false: print("reportActivityStarted is false before assignment") // <- your logic goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Unheilig: No, I think you should undelete your answer. It did explain how to create a private variable for this scenario. It's a different approach and it would be nice having it explained here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `get`, `set` you may need to have another variable to save the value on it in `set` and request it in `get`. like this:

```
var _reportActivityStarted = false 
var reportActivityStarted:Bool {
        set {
             _reportActivityStarted = newValue
            if _reportActivityStarted {
                //Operations when boolean is true
            }else{
                //Operations when boolean is false
            }
        }
    get{
        return _reportActivityStarted
    }
}
```

But from what I see in you code sample you don't need `set` and `get` at all. you just need to use `didSet` instead. like this

```
var reportActivityStarted:Bool {
            didSet {
            if reportActivityStarted {
                //Operations when boolean is true
            }else{
                //Operations when boolean is false
            }
        }
}
```